# How to fix upgrade issue from nexus 2.14.1-01 to 3.1.0-04

Tags: upgrade, nexus

I try to upgrade from 2.14.1-01 to 3.1.0-04. When I invoke upgrade I got: [image]

The nexus 2 log contains the following:

> 2016-11-22 15:06:21 INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-14] *TASK
>   com.sonatype.nexus.migrationagent.repository.RepositoryMigrationTask -
>   Scheduled task (RepositoryMigrationTask) canceled :: Upgrading
>   repository: vaadin-addons (started 2016-11-22T15:06:19+03:00, runtime
>   0:00:01.710) 2016-11-22 15:06:21 INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-14] *TASK
>   org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.application.DefaultNexusConfiguration
>   - Applying Nexus Configuration due to changes in [Scheduled Tasks] made by *TASK... 2016-11-22 15:06:22 WARN  [qtp10032359-104] *UNKNOWN
>   org.sonatype.sisu.siesta.server.internal.mappers.ThrowableExceptionMapper
>   - java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method extract() on null object java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method
>   extract() on null object  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:57)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.sonatype.nexus.migrationagent.rest.RepositoryChangelogResource$_get_closure1$_closure2.doCall(RepositoryChangelogResource.groovy:115) ~[na:na]

( I have published the full stack trace here http://pastebin.com/byjfeC8L )

Could you please show me the way to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there, can you file an issue for this at https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS ? That would be good for us to help you out :)

Comment: @DarthHater: thank you, I have put the issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occures if the previous upgrade process has been canceled. To repare upgrade process as the workaround you can manually stop nexus 2 service and delete the directory {{sonatype-work/nexus/db/migrationagent}}, restart nexus 2 or wait for nexus 2.14.2 with fixes.